# Creating my own SDP file

Tags: audio, sdp

Currently I have created a working peer-to-peer communication using two browsers using [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer).

My problem is that I need to create my own SDP file and not have it generated. So far, I have copy pasted a working SDP file (Printed when a successful call was made) and am slowly modifying it. Although, with great difficult to get it working. So far I have.

```
"v=0
o=- 3427781692201307364 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio data
a=msid-semantic: WMS U9yTSe3lyMtWw6tNcSvbzKK9TnxpIRxLZCbW
m=audio 36700 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 172.16.214.18
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=candidate:4150813302 1 udp 2122260223 172.16.214.18 36700 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=ice-ufrag:1IIc
a=ice-pwd:HwiOe9O5NcjOB/xVH5GSkiqb
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 76:57:AB:96:ED:1F:86:3E:AD:CF:9F:C2:D1:66:9C:8F:91:92:AF:11:EE:F8:79:38:C5:F0:87:FA:F4:31:43:3D
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=ssrc:61095280 cname:0gTP3tO0LNbaJlRe
a=ssrc:61095280 msid:U9yTSe3lyMtWw6tNcSvbzKK9TnxpIRxLZCbW aec10cc7-461e-496a-87cd-9305cbb5b1f8
a=ssrc:61095280 mslabel:U9yTSe3lyMtWw6tNcSvbzKK9TnxpIRxLZCbW
a=ssrc:61095280 label:aec10cc7-461e-496a-87cd-9305cbb5b1f8
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:30
a=ice-ufrag:1IIc
a=ice-pwd:HwiOe9O5NcjOB/xVH5GSkiqb
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 76:57:AB:96:ED:1F:86:3E:AD:CF:9F:C2:D1:66:9C:8F:91:92:AF:11:EE:F8:79:38:C5:F0:87:FA:F4:31:43:3D
a=setup:active
a=mid:data
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
"
```

I understand that most are not changed, and some are just ID's. But I am simply connecting peer-peer over a local network. How much of this can I simply remove? I just need to create a connection and stream RTP, I do not care if it is encrypted. What is the simplest SDP file I can create to create the connection.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Can you be more specific? Is there something not working as you expected? Or is everything working but you still want to improve something?

Answer (score 0):

https://webrtchacks.com/the-minimum-viable-sdp/ walks through the process of "compressing" the SDP if that is what you need. If you are trying to connect different machines without exchanging an offer and answer that is not possible. Nor is it possible to turn off encryption.